# Opening multiples a report in more than one tab (Access Database)

Tags: ms-access

I have an access database that has a report. There is a button I click to open it, and everything works fine if I just want one report. However, if I want to open the same report twice, say to compare the two, it does not work. Instead of opening the second report in a separate tab, it just takes me to the tab that has the first report on it. Is there a way that I can make the report always open in a new tab?

Comment: Please share the code behind that button, so I can modify it to open it in a different tab.

Comment: The button just uses the generic "OpenReport" macro.

Comment: Well, convert it to VBA, or provide info like report name, view, filter, etc.

Comment: Okay, it looks like this:                                                                                       Report Name: Labels and Remarks  ||   View: Report   ||  Filter Name:
(blank)   ||   Where Condition: (blank)   ||  Window Mode: Normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this quite easily, with a little VBA. You do need to add a module to the report and to the form/report with the button:

On the buttons on click event:

```vb
Public Sub MyButton_Click()
    Dim rpt As New [Report_Labels and Remarks]
    rpt.Visible = True
    Set rpt.Myself = rpt
End Sub
```

On the report, in the module:

```vb
Public Myself As Report
Private Sub Report_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Set Myself = Nothing
End If
```

Note that you might need to rewrite other code, like macros closing the report, `DoCmd.Close` and code fetching values from the report using the `Reports` collection, since there are multiple instances of the report.